# Python port scanning sample

Tags: python, network-programming, port, network-scan

I'm trying to learn python for a task I have and I ran a sample of port scanner in python :

```
 for port in range(1,1025):  
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print ("Port {}: \t Open".format(port))
        sock.close()
```

and it looks like connecting to the server in each port takes a lot of time, is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python port scanning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688967/python-port-scanning)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on multi-threading and especially on Thread Pools with a limited number of threads to benefit from parallelism while preventing from too many number of simultaneous connections (which will certainly result in errors like "too many files opened").